# How to rename controls in IB?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, controls, rename

I remember being able to rename controls in IB.  But it doesn't seem to work anymore.  Does anyone know how to rename the controls in IB?  IB seems to default to the text value as the default name.  This is not an issue until a text value spans multiple lines.  The IB sidebar become unreadable.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/77u9m.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the identity inspector (third tab) there is a value called Label (under identity), you can rename it there.

Comment: Thank you!  I remember being able to click and then slow-click on the sidebar to rename it.  I wonder why they changed this behavior.